# Rotate all the objects in the array in the same way

Tags: modifiers

I want to make windows blinds. I create slats by using Array modifier.
Now I want each slat to rotate in the same way. When I rotate them now - they are also moved.
How to make it in an easy way?
In 3dsMax I was able to create array of objects as an instances of the original one and when I was rotating the original one, all the rest rotated the same way.

Comment: You can rotate them in edit mode, but that may have repercussions if you wanted to edit later..  You could always instance on points in geonodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An old-school method would be, in Edit Mode, with all selected, to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> give your slat a *Hook* modifier. Its mesh can then be controlled by an Empty, without transforming the object, so the *Array* transform remains constant.

[image]

The controlling Empty can be given a *Limit Rotation* constraint, to prevent the blind from flipping out, or intersecting itself.

[image]

But if you're making a re-usable Venetian Blind asset, with a convenient interface for variations, then a Geometry Nodes modifier is probably a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own more powerful array modifiers using geometry nodes.

[image: Geometry Nodes setup creating instances of the input geometry on a mesh line allowing them to be rotated based on input]

In the above image you can control the count, offset factor, and rotation (in radians) in the modifier:

[image: A Geometry Nodes modifier with Count, Factor, and Angle parameters]

Comment: Tip: if you connect a group socket to the socket of a node that uses degrees as value (e.g. `Curve Spiral`) and then disconnect it again, the group socket remembers the setting and you can change the angle in degrees instead of radians. Alternatively you can use a `Math` node and the setting *To Radians*.

Comment: @quellenform .. sneaky !