# Rotate each iteration of an arrayed object on their own axis

Tags: modifiers

I've got a cylindrical object arrayed 33 times, and I wanted each iteration to rotate on their respective y-axis.

With fairly standard array settings it looks like this gif:

[image: Array rotation]

But preferably I would like it to rotate like this:

[image: How I want it to look]

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: how shall we help you, if we have no idea how you made your rotation? just with keyframes? with geometry nodes? with modifiers? we have no idea because you didn't give us any information

Comment: Don't use Array modifiers, arrays are not for instancing objects. They will create a new huge mesh that is neither beneficial for performance nor animation

Comment: It would be easier with a Geometry Nodes modifier tree

Comment: @Chris so I just used keyframed the cylinder to rotate linearly on the y-axis. I'm trying to make it part of a rigid body simulation, hence why I am not using nodes. Perhaps I will just rotate the original cylinder and then duplicate it 33 times

Comment: @Confused_User: yes, then geometry nodes makes no sense because it doesn't work with rigid body

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/289743/35559

Answer (score 0):

The *Array* modifier gives every element the same transform with respect to the previous one. (A matrix-multiply.)

Sometimes it would be useful to have some sort of additive step per element, instead. Various alternatives can be made with Geometry Nodes.. here's one, which may be useful in your case:

[image]

See how you get along with it.

[image]

[image]

The 'Realize' switch might be necessary for some shading purposes, or to make geometry available to other momdifiers further down the stack.